# opencvとGPUにおける実行ファイルのエラーをcmakeを使わずにエラーを解決したいです。

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

**ソースコード**はこちらです。

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> // インクルードファイル指定
//#include <opencv2/opencv_lib.hpp> // 静的リンクライブラリの指定

#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>

#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core2413d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgproc2413d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_highgui2413d.lib")

#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_gpu2413d.lib")

using namespace cv; // 名前空間の指定

int main() {
    cv::Mat src_img = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\Daito\\Desktop\\DTWW6svVQAEvgvk.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    if (src_img.empty()) return -1;

    gpu::GpuMat gpuSrc(src_img);
    gpu::GpuMat gpuDst;
    gpu::Laplacian(gpuSrc, gpuDst, 0);
    cv::Mat dst(gpuDst);

    cv::imshow("C:\\Users\\Daito\\Desktop\\DTWW6svVQAEvgvk.jpg", src_img);
    cv::imshow("C:\\Users\\Daito\\Desktop\\DTWW6svVQAEvgvk.jpg", dst);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

**エラーコード**がこちらです。

```
OpenCV Error: No GPU support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in EmptyFuncTable::mallocPitch, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\dynamicuda\include\opencv2/dynamicuda/dynamicuda.hpp, line 126
```

Cmakeを使わずに解決したいのは勉強の一環としてであり、あえて手作業で行いたいと思い今回のような質問をいたしました。

以下はマルチポストです。
https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12188355392
https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/10399808.html

Comment: cmakeを使わずに、何を使ってコンパイルするのでしょうか? ただのmake それとも Visual stdio ? どちらにしてもコンパイル条件の問題と考えます。

Comment: Visual stdio 2015 を用いて解決したいと考えています。ちなみに、ビルドするプログラム内で使う関数などを定義したり、あるいはプログラムを改良する事でエラーを解決することはできないでしょうか？

Comment: エラーの内容からすると、リンクしているライブラリがGPUサポートが無いと言っています。ソースコードの問題と言うより、ビルド環境の問題です。ビルドに使用したライブラリ、ビルド環境を確認すべきと思います。 また、マルチポストは、どこからも回答が得られないかも知れません。環境を明記して、質問する場所を絞った方が良いと思います。

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。ビルドに使用したライブラリとはopencv_core340.libなどのことでしょうか？Cmakeによって得られたOpencv.slnをビルドする際にライブラリが見つからないとでます。しかしライブラリを指定できません。ビルド環境はOpencv3.4.0,visual studio 2015,windows10 64bit,などのことでしょうか？不明な点がありましたら教えてください。

Comment: 「ビルド環境は...」を質問文に記載すべきかと思います。 ライブラリが見つからないエラーを合わせて記載した方が良いと思います。別の質問もいくつか投稿されているようですが、そちらで解決しませんか?

Comment: クロスポスト: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49598789/5989200

Comment: クロスポスト: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49613413/5989200

Answer (score 1):

公式で配布しているバイナリはGPU対応していません。CUDA対応させたいなら自前でビルドするしかないです。

下のサイトが参考になると思います。

https://jamesbowley.co.uk/build-compile-opencv-3-4-in-windows-with-cuda-9-0-and-intel-mkl-tbb/

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。早速参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: あの、思ったのですが、nvccでライブラリの元となるソースコードをコンパイルして、そのライブラリ(バイナリ)をgccで使えば、cmakeを使わなくても良いのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 自前ビルドをするなら、CMAKEより簡単な方法は思いつきません。また、VisualStudio2017最新版ですとCUDAのコンパイルできないですよ。手間をかけたくないなら2015をダウンロードしてWindows10のアカウントを英語にしてからコンパイルするとよいです。日本語だとコードページの問題でコンパイルエラーが出まくってSDKのソースをUNICODEで保存しなおさなくてはならいですし、それをやるにはCUDAのインストールするときのディレクトリを変更しなくてはならないです。私が紹介したサイトでコンパイル済のバイナリを配布しているのでそれを使うのが手間がないと思います。私はCUDA込みで自前のコンフィグで最新のOPENCVをコンパイルできる方法を発見するまで3か月以上かかりました。

Comment: 回答が間違ってたみたい。Windows＋OPENCV＋CUDAを手っ取り早くという話でしたらGCCとかそういうことを考えず、私が紹介しているサイトで配布しているバイナリを使うのが一番簡単だと思います。CUDA込みのOPENCVを自前でコンパイルするとめちゃくちゃ時間がかかります。3時間は覚悟したほうが良いです。

Comment: すごく助かります。本当にどうもありがとうございます。